# how to display multiplication table by defining function

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to display the multiplication table using loops but how do I make a function that can do the same thing? Pls tell me the whole program

Answer (score 0):

```
#In this method the value of the highest multiple is passed in mult
#base is base value which will be multiplied
#this function runs from mult to 1
def multiply_rev(base,mult):
    if(mult == 0):
        return
    else:
        print("{} * {} = {}".format(base,mult,base*mult))
        multiply_rev(base,mult-1)


#In this method the value of the lowest multiple is passed in mult
#base is base value which will be multiplied
##this function runs from mult to 10
def multiply_for(base,mult):
    if(mult == 11):
        return
    else:
        print("{} * {} = {}".format(base,mult,base*mult))
        multiply_for(base,mult+1)        

multiply_rev(2,10)
print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
multiply_for(2,1)
```

This is a typical example for recursion. Google recursion for more informaion.